# Words "transitoriness" and "transientness" not in all dictionaries

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, dictionaries

I know that many adjectives can be transformed into nouns by adding -ness suffix. Usually, I check if the word is present in a dictionary (preferably Merriam-Webster). This time I was not satisfied with the search result so I tried other dictionaries.

These are the results for  "**transitoriness**" and "**transientness**"?

```
                                "transitoriness"    "transientness"

merriam-webster.com:                  YES                 NO

oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com:       NO                  NO

collinsdictionary.com                 YES                 YES

dictionary.com                        YES                 YES

dictionary.cambridge.org              NO                  NO

thefreedictionary.com                 YES                 YES
```

Google Books Ngram Viewer shows that in recent past the occurrence of "transitoriness" is 40 times higher than of "transientness".

[image: Google Books Ngram Viewer]

My **first question** is: Because there is no official US/UK English dictionary and there does not seem to be a consensus among popular online dictionaries, how do I decide if set word is legitimate or proper to use?

My **second question** is: When there is a word like "transientness" that is clearly used a lot less than alternative synonyms, is it alright if I pick up such word and use it, let's say in a graduation speech?

I understand that maybe there are no clear answers, but I would welcome all opinions and advice.

Thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with [transcience](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transience)? Why choose a rarely used variant of a common word?

Comment: _Transient nature_ is more usual

Comment: Thanks for your tips. Yes, I could use these alternatives. The reason why I chose the other options was that phonetically it goes better with the word flow. Do you guys have any general advice, I can use in future, to the questions I asked? It does not have to concern specifically the two words.